# Geo searching with thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

**How do you pass multiple parameters into a search using thinking sphinx? Or how can you create advanced search fields using thinking sphinx?**

*Background: I am creating a website that allows manufacturers to post freight that they need moved across the country. Carriers need to be able to search through the posted loads based upon their current location and have a list returned of the most profitable loads which they can then bid on. Carriers will have two inputs, their current location and the radius in which they are willing to travel to pick up a load. Thinking Sphinx looks like it shoud be able to handle all of these problems, however the documentation does not go into much detail for complex search queries.*

I have a model called Load which has the following attributes and their respective types:

```
# :latitude => float
# :longitude => float
# :delivery_date => date
# :delivery_latitude => float
# :delivery_longitude => float
# :weight => integer
# :truck_type => string
# :price => decimal
# :distance => float
# :delta => boolean
```

I have included an index on the model as follows:

```
define_index do
 indexes :commodity
 indexes :truck_type
 set_property :delta => true
 has weight, distance      
 has "Radians(latitude)", :as => :latitude, :type => :float
 has "Radians(longitude)", :as => :longitude, :type => :float
end
```

I have also defined a search class into my lib folder which uses the [ruby geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem for all of my geocoding needs. This code has not been tested so I am unsure of its correctness, but I am including it to see if my thought process is correct.

```
class Search 

  #Inputs for the search will be a current_location string, and a distance integer (miles)

  # Variable needed to convert to imperial values
  METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.344 

  # Expression used to rank the loads
  SORT_EXPRESSION = "Sorting function tbd, combination of weight, distance, and price"

def self.execute(keyword, var = {}) 
  @search_options = { :page => var[:page] || 1, 
                    :per_page => Load::PER_PAGE }

  unless (keyword).blank? #I am unsure if this is correct
  @geocode = Geocoder.coordinates(keyword) #returns an array ex.[keyword_latitude, keyword_longitude]


    if @geocode.success and @geocode.accuracy > 1 
    lat = (@geocode.first / 180.0) * Math::PI 
    lng = (@geocode.last / 180.0) * Math::PI 

    @search_options.merge!(:geo => [lat, lng], 
                           :sort_mode => :expr, 
                           :sort_by => SORT_EXPRESSION, 
                           :with => { "@geodist" => 0.0..(travel_distance * METERS_PER_MILE) }) 
    end 
  end
 Load.search(keyword, travel_distance, @search_options)
end
```

The goal is to be able to go into any controller and define an instance variable and call this search module to return the values. ( @loads = Search.execute(params[:search] ) I am also do not know how I would go about displaying the results of the search

**Has anyone had to run a similar type of geo-search with thinking sphinx that could share their setup? I need to run delayed deltas as well but the documentation is clearer on that subject.**

Comment: To do anything beyond the most basic queries, you're going to end up having to refer to the [Sphinx manual](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/), because you'll be using the 'extended' search mode (`:match_mode => :extended`).

Comment: Incidentally, I never did get Sphinx's built-in geodistance magic to work, and ended up writing my own sort expression, using the SQL GEODIST() function.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot here to grok, but if I'm understanding this right, it all comes down to the search call, where you want Loads within a certain distance from a geographical point, right? If so, then just remove travel_distance as the second argument from your search request, and it should be fine:

```
Load.search keyword,
  :geo       => [lat, lng], 
  :sort_mode => :expr, 
  :sort_by   => SORT_EXPRESSION, 
  :with      => { "@geodist" => 0.0..(travel_distance * METERS_PER_MILE) }
```

But given what I'm suggesting really isn't all that different to what you've already got, I'm wondering if I understand the question correctly...

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is all about the search call, however I am still confused about incorporating the travel distance into the search options. By not including travel distance into the search call wouldn't it not be included in the search?

Comment: It's there in the filter (`:with`) - that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel and finagle Sphinx into doing what you want, you could make your Freight/Listing model location-aware using the `geocoder` gem. This will store the lat/long of the the freight listing in your database and adds geolocation query methods to your model. This allows you find fright listings within a specified distance like so:

```
@results = FreightListing.near('77033', 50) # Finds all listings that are within 50 miles of the zip code 77033
```

More info here: http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: Although it is nice to find what is near me, for this use case I need to order the search results by the profitability of each load, and whether or not it is still available. So just finding what is near the person is not helpful. Unfortunately for this case I think I have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In Sphinx's defence, you're not reinventing the wheel - it has had support for geo searching for years.